# Upgrading Next11 to Next12

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Attempting to upgrade Next 11 to Next 12. When I bump the next dependency to the latest

```
npm i next@latest
```

The application compiles successfully in the terminal but when I launch the page I get the following error on screen.

[image]

[image]

Looking at the upgrade docs for Next doesn't show anything apparent to me that would cause this error just by switching from 11 to 12.

Any help would be appreciated.

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "3.5.10",
        "@wordpress/url": "^3.1.1",
        "@wpengine/headless": "^0.6.3",
        "eslint-config-next": "^12.1.6",
        "graphql": "^15.5.1",
        "html-react-parser": "^1.2.7",
        "next": "^12.1.6",
        "next-transpile-modules": "^9.0.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.1.1",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.1.0",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.11",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.1",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.15.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^6.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-use-encapsulation": "^1.0.0",
        "husky": "^7.0.0",
        "open-cli": "^6.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "typescript": "^4.3.2",
        "wait-on": "^5.2.1"
    }
```

Comment: I think you should check your node version

Comment: From package.json

"engines": {
  "node": ">=15.0.0"
 },

I don't think it's the node version unfortunately.